# Cannot export Test case in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to export a Test Case in Selenium IDE (in JUnit format), but everytime I am getting the same error:Test '001_PROVISIONALQC2657CONGCSourceCP400600HFA' has a problem: Invalid command ''

Even if I set all the lines inside the script as comments I am still unable to export it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because of the comments added to the script, and also because of a Close command for the URL that was opened on the first place. After removing these lines the export took place successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Save project and reopen. This did the trick.